# SQL putting (-) sign in front of my output

Tags: sql, oracle

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1shky.png)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p22ac.png)

I need to write a statement that produce a customer report that show all customers, accounts and transactions. Include accounts with no transactions. Solve using JOIN...ON. And there needs to be - sign in my transaction_amount output if the transaction_type is debit.

I tried using format, if else, when then ...etc

This is what I have so far. Can't figure out putting - sign for my output.

```
select c.first_name "First", c.surname "Last",c.date_entered "Acct Date",
       t.account_type "Type", t.transaction_number "Trans #", 
       t.transaction_date "Trs Date", t.transaction_amount "Amount"
  from wgb_customer c
  join wgb_transaction t on (c.customer_number=t.customer_number) 
 order by 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: `sqlplus` is a product that belong to `oracle` database, it seems skew using `sqlplus` and `mysql` together as tags.

Comment: Could you please add the table descriptions?

Comment: First hint: use a `left outer join` since also the customers with no transactions should be reported.

Comment: So what is the DB system you are using? Let us know!

Comment: For Oracle, you'd have to use the DECODE function. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Comment: Im using oracle sql plus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to join on the accounts table as well and use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the transactions table since it should create output also for the account with no transactions.
Furthermore, use a `CASE` statement on the transaction type in order to add a minus sign.
Something like this (I didn't try it though; it may even not compile):

```
SELECT          cust.first_name         AS first_name,
                cust.surname            AS last_name,
                acct.account_type       AS acct_type,
                acct.date_created       AS acct_date,
                trns.transaction_number AS trans_nr,
                trns.transaction_date   AS trans_date,
                CASE
                  WHEN trns.transaction_type IS NULL THEN NULL
                  WHEN trns.transaction_type = 'D'   THEN '-' || TO_CHAR(transaction_amount, 'L99G999D99')
                  ELSE TO_CHAR(transaction_amount, 'L99G999D99')
                END                     AS amount
FROM            wgb_customer cust
JOIN            wgb_account  acct
  ON            acct.customer_number = cust.customer_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN wgb_transaction trns
             ON trns.customer_number = acct.customer_number
            AND trns.account_type    = acct.account_type
ORDER BY        last_name,
                first_name,
                acct_type,
                acct_date,
                trans_nr;
```